# App getting stuck in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, multithreading, activity-indicator

This is my code:

```
        LoadViewController *loadingViewController = [[LoadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:loadingViewController.view];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) , ^{
    [Util deleteAllObjects:@"Unit"];
    for (NSDictionary *eachUnit in serviceData) {
        //insert in DB
        AppDelegate* appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        Unit *unit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unit" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        unit.id_unidade = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"id"];
        unit.title = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"title"];
        unit.image = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"image"];
        unit.address = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"address"];
        unit.desc = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"desc"];
        unit.coord = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"coord"];

        NSError *error;

        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Ops,fail: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"before");
    [self fillUnits];
    NSLog(@"after");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        NSLog(@"reload");
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [loadingViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"after reload");

    });
});
```

It shows until the NSLog(@"after"), but never gets on the NSLog(@"reload").
Any clues??

Comment: what is this (void) in  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)?

Comment: I think we cannot deduce the problem from this snippet. You might be blocking the main queue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: That is part of the initialize method of that class...It gets called after the user taps the cancel button in a UIAlertView... indeed the UI gets stuck showing the alert...

Comment: LoadViewController is called after click on cancel button i suppose.. right? and this looks good?

Comment: This code is in a different class from the alert, but yes...the click on the cancel button calls this method above

Answer (score 1):

In your completion handler, you need to ensure that all methods send to a managed object or to a managed object context are executed on their respective *execution context* using `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        Unit *unit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unit"  inManagedObjectContext:context];

        unit.id_unidade = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"id"];
        unit.title = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"title"];
        unit.image = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"image"];
        unit.address = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"address"];
        unit.desc = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"desc"];
        unit.coord = [eachUnit objectForKey:@"coord"];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Ops,fail: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

If your managed object will be accessed in the main thread, it's mandatory that the *execution context* equals the main thread.

You can read more in the Apple Docs: [NSManagedObjectContext Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html), especially chapter "Concurrency".

Comment: When I try using this, it crashes:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.

Comment: Then you have created a managed object context using "thread confinement" (`NSConfinementConcurrencyType`). This is somewhat obsolete. You should use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. If you use "thread confinement" you MUST ensure you execute any method sent to a context or a managed object on the same *thread* where the managed context has been created. With the other concurrency model you ensure basically the same requirement with `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` which execute on the specified *queue*.

Comment: And how can I do that? I am just using the regular context provided by Xcode when we create a app with CoreData.

Comment: Please follow the link provided in my answer. The apple documentation shows how to create a managed object context: `- (id)initWithConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)type`. Please note also, that Xcode does not provide a `NSManagedContext`, it's *you*. Core Data is a complex topic. I would suggest to read *all* documentation related to Core Data from Apple.

Comment: Well...when you create an app with CoreData it creates some methods in the AppDelegate, such as (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext, but thanks anyway, I will take a better look at the documentation

Comment: I never used that template directly, since I usually create my own "Core Data Stack". The Core Data Stack is an important concept. The recommended basic stack has *two* managed object contexts: one is the _root_ context which is associated with a persistent store and runs on a private queue (`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`). The _main context_ is actually a _child_ of this root context using the "Main Queue" (`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`). Usually, you use the _main context_ for most operations requiring to be executed on the main thread, e.g. UIKit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44808/discussion-between-alexandre-lins-and-couchdeveloper)